# Why are agricultural requests based on holiday timing?

Tags: tefilla, calendar

There are a few changes to the amida which reflect the changes in the seasons -- we add (or change to) mashiv haru'ach umorid hagashem (or geshem) at Shmini Atzeret (and back at Pesach) and switch TO v'tein bracha on Pesach.

These changes indicate an awareness in our tefillot of the need for certain changes in nature, and the v'tein bracha is a request: we don't want rain when it would be inappropriate. This is based on our farming needs.

However, Pesach ranges in our calendar from [year](https://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/161959/why-is-this-pesach-the-earliest-since-1899.html) to year (March 25th to approximately April 24) while the needs of the soil and the sowing and reaping cycle stay the same. In a "late" year, we would be praying for rain for almost a month more than we might need it (or in an early year, for a month less).

Why would our date for changing from v'tein tal umatar livracha be based in a lunar based holiday which moves back and forth through two solar months instead of on a solar date which reflects the yearly agricultural cycle more precisely?

Comment: If you didn't use a solar calendar daily you might not be wondering this

Comment: The agriculture needs vary with random weather patterns too. If anything an actively managed leap year calendar could be more accurate than a fixed solar date!

Comment: I don't think that the change of the seasons is a lunar-based event regardless of how I label my days. If I am not going to change my davening yearly, based on satellites and projections, then it should be based in an established cycle.

Comment: the established cycle is the calendar. Using a time not on the calendar is bizarre. That's what you are proposing. (Weather projections is indeed how it's supposed to work but now we have a fixed calendar.)

Comment: Does "Spring" exist on a halachic calendar? I was under the impression that the leap month was meant to ensure that the lunar holiday stays within the solar season. A farmer would probably know when he wanted rain to start or stop and I doubt it would vary by a month year to year.

Comment: This site seems to ask the reverse https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2060070/jewish/Why-Is-the-Prayer-for-Rain-Based-on-the-Civil-Calendar.htm

Comment: the premise of that article is indeed like I said that using the solar calendar is bizarre and is based on hard to understand opinions.

Comment: 1. Your question is practically limited to approx plus-minus one week of difference where it might be "detectable", because the lunar calendar only goes +/- two weeks from the solar. 2. Please note that the prayers were only "widely accepted" long after the 2nd Temple destruction, so people lived for millennia without special preset prayers to G-d. 3. As the rest of the prayer has little to do with agriculture, this addition changes very little in overall meaning.

Comment: You say "*we don't want rain when it would be inappropriate. This is based on our farming needs."* - is it true, If one was praying for the rain all year long (similar to the European climate) what would be wrong with it agriculture-wise? Is the rain in the summer bad for the crops? Isn't this the reason Israel is constantly developing watering systems?

Comment: I'm trtying to follow the various comments, so excuse if I'm asking what's already been discussed. Perhaps, you're missing an important point. Pesach, originally, was moved based on agricultural needs. Prior to the fixed calendar, the main concern was not as much "spring" but a concern of if the barley would ripen in time for 16th Nissan. Theoretically, that would allow for 2 consecutive leap years based on weather and agricultural needs. (I don't know if that actually occurred. I may ask a Q about that.)